# memcpy to concat smaller arrays into bigger ones

Tags: c, arrays, buffer, memcpy

I am trying to figure out how to take small bits of data and combine it into a bigger array using memcopy. This is in c and not c++.

```
memcpy(void* dest, void* src, size_t n);
```

so I set a dest buffer a src buffer and the amount of data to copy.

I've been trying but I am not getting the results that I expect. I just want to take 8 copies of the 4 value float array and pack it into the one 32 value float array.

```
float test[32];
float tmp[4] = {9, 8, 7, 6};
printf("size of tmp:%lu sizeof tmp/ tmp[0]:%lu\n", sizeof(tmp),
       (sizeof(tmp) / sizeof(tmp[0])));
printf("============\n");
```

doing the printf to check the sizes, 4 float is 16 and the size of 1 float is 4, just sanity checks on my part.

```
memcpy(test, tmp + (sizeof(tmp)*0), sizeof(tmp));  //this is the initial offset at 0
memcpy(test + (sizeof(tmp)*1), tmp, sizeof(tmp)); //this should copy to the test buffer plus and offset of 16 bytes
memcpy(test + (sizeof(tmp)*2), tmp, sizeof(tmp)); //etc

for (int i = 0; i < 32; i++) {
    printf("%f ", test[i]);
    if (i > 1 && i % 4 == 0) printf("\n");
}
```

it seems like only the initial 4 bytes are copied and all the subsequent ones fail.

The reason for using offsets and such is that I want to generalize this but even writing out such a simple use case of just copying 16 byte offset it doesn't work.

I get this printout:

```
size of tmp:16 sizeof tmp/ tmp[0]:4
============
9.000000 8.000000 7.000000 6.000000 0.000000
0.000000 0.000000 0.000000 1602397014491231940111075790290944.000000
0.000000 -6544621971295550046208.000000 0.000000 0.000000
0.000000 1602345021009581954139530027073536.000000 0.000000 9.000000
8.000000 7.000000 6.000000 0.000000
0.000000 -1796536614528950701815653974964961280.000000 0.000000 0.000000
0.000000 0.000000 0.000000 1602345021009581954139530027073536.000000
```

now i can understand the random numbers means the memory hasn't be properly initialized but I can't figure out why the memcpy isn't working as expected.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

test is a float pointer, sizeof(tmp) is byte in size.

Pointer arithmetic will cause you to go to a wrong offset.

try:

```
memcpy(test + ((sizeof(tmp)/sizeof(tmp[0]))*1), tmp, sizeof(tmp))
```

Answer (score 0):

Just write readable code and all problems will usually go away:

```
void copy_floats (float*        dest, 
                  const float*  src, 
                  size_t        items_n,
                  size_t        copies_n)
{
  for(size_t i=0; i<copies_n; i++)
  {
    memcpy(&dest[i * items_n], 
           src, 
           sizeof(*src) * items_n);
  }
}
```

Caller:

```
copy_floats(test, tmp, 4, 8);
```

---

(if you want to be predantic/advanced, declare parameters as `float* restrict dest` and `const float* restrict src` to allow better optimization)